# Build a new map consisting of the column labels from A and B in Java

Tags: java

Build and return a new map such that the new map contains all of the keys from labelsFromA and all of the keys from labelsFromB. The new map sends each key to an integer index. If there are n keys, then each integer index from 0 to n-1 is used once.

```
private static Map<String, Integer> joinLabels(Map<String, Integer> labelsFromA, Map<String, Integer> labelsFromB){
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should help:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> joinLabels(Map<String, Integer> labelsFromA, Map<String, Integer> labelsFromB){
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    int i = 0;
    for(String key : labelsFromA.keySet()){
       if(!map.containsKey(key)){
          map.put(key, i++);
       }
     }
     for(String key : labelsFromB.keySet()){
       if(!map.containsKey(key)){
          map.put(key, i++);
       }
     }
    return map;
}
```

All I am doing is, iterating over keyset of both the maps. If the new map doesn't contains the key in current iteration, then I am inserting it intu the map with a value i with a post increment.

Though, base on your question the actual solution should be this:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> joinLabels(Map<String, Integer> labelsFromA, Map<String, Integer> labelsFromB){
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    int i = 0;
    for(String key : labelsFromA.keySet()){
       if(!map.containsValue(key)){
          map.put(i++, key);
       }
     }
     for(String key : labelsFromB.keySet()){
       if(!map.containsValue(key)){
          map.put(i++, key);
       }
     }
    return map;
}
```

as every key need to be stored against a numeric index as per your question!!